# Initialize radio button as checked

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having trouble initializing a radio button as checked. What I mean is when I open the form, none of my 2 radio buttons are checked, but they work fine after I check on of them. I tried setting one of them as checked in the Form constructor, but it still appears as unchecked:

```
public frmPreferences(Capitals capit)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    radEnglish.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
radEnglish.Enabled = true
```

This does not set the CheckBox to a Checked state, it enables the control.  You could do this in the designer, or you could use the line

```
radEnglish.Checked = true;
```

For WPF it's

```
radEnglish.IsChecked = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

The enabled property doesn't check the control, it (not surprisingly) enables it. Use this instead:

```
radEnglish.Checked = true;
```